# domToImage code throwing security error (Dom Exception 18) on iOS browsers only

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I am trying to use the [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) plugin. Here is my sample code.

[www.avarachan.com/test.html](http://www.avarachan.com/test.html)

IT works fine on desktop, but on iphone, it throws the error

**security error dom exception 18**

I tried the following htaccess options

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Error remains. it seems to be working on chrome on android ( I tested using browserstack). Only, iOS chrome and safari keeps throwing the exception.Even with just with a div and text.

THere is a similar library, https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas, and it works on mobile. But the library is not as good as dom-to-image. Can someone with js and canvas knowldge look into how the later seems to work ok on iOS, and may be suggest a solution to make dom-to-image work on mobile?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? We're running into the same problem using the html2canvas library.

Comment: @jessica This issue was only there with dom-to-image plugin as it uses svg and foreignobject node. html2canvas should have no issues like that. Infact I ended up going back to html2canvas and all is fine there. (well had to do some quirks for my specific case).

Comment: maybe it isn't the exact same issue, but we have been getting the DOM Exception 18 error when trying to work with an html2canvas that has an SVG embedded in it. We ended up taking out the SVG for now. Thanks anyway for the reply!

Comment: @jessica In my experience, setting cross origin stuff wont help in many cases when the image is coming from another server. Some browsers are more racist than others I would say ;) especially mobile.

Comment: strange thing is, the SVG source is embedded inline in the css, i.e. using `url('data:image/svg+xml;...')` and a base-64 encoded image. taking it out fixed the error, so it was definitely from that. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

"DOM Exception 18 usually means you exceeded the quota allowed on the device (50MB), although in some environments it's because Apple removed WebSQL support (e.g. WKWebView)."

Source: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4234

Comment: I am not sure this is the case, as the test page has a div with some text. At max few kb.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

and try to reduce the quality

Comment: Tried this, and few other methods, ends up throwing error that it cannot load js